# Spring JPA Can I pass a pojo to a stored procedure?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

In Spring Data JPA, I know that I can have something like

```
public interface MyRepo extends JPARepository<MyObject, Integer>
```

And this will generate a Save method to which I can pass a MyObject and have it be persisted in the database.

Can I do something similar with stored procedures? As in, I pass a MyObject to a properly annotated method in my Repository and the fields of that object will be used as arguments to the Stored Procedure?

I know I could simply add each field as a separate parameter and do it that way but...there are lots of 'em. Also this is Oracle if that matters.

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: There is a section in the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.stored-procedures But when you have to deal a lot with stored procedures you should definitely check out jOOQ https://jooq.org

Comment: Jooq looks extremely cool! I can't use it in this project but I will definitely take a look at that in the future